# How to avoid upcast for columns with missing values when creating dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a pandas dataframe from a json string. To be able to flatten the nested json source data I need to use `pandas.json_normalize()` (instead of `pandas.read_json()`). In the source data some of the columns are integer type and sporadically have missing values. This causes the column to be "upcast" to float:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
  { "c1": 1, "c2": 1, "c3": 1.01 },
  { "c1": 2, "c3": 2.02 },
  { "c1": 3, "c2": 3, "c3": 3.03 }
]

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df, "\n\n", df.dtypes)
```

which results in

```
   c1   c2    c3
0   1  1.0  1.01
1   2  NaN  2.02
2   3  3.0  3.03 

c1      int64
c2    float64
c3    float64
```

(I have stripped down the example to the crux of the matter. In reality the source data is far more complex.)

Applying `df.convert_dtypes()` kind of solves the problem after the fact but the function feels a bit creepy to me because I don't really know what it does to the other columns that I don't want to change (such as datetime columns).

Is there a way to avoid this "upcast" in the first place without affecting other columns?

Comment: i don't think it's possible with `pd.json_normalize` the solution is to use the `dtype` `np.Int64` (note the capital I) you could try `df.select_dtypes('float').astype('Int64')` and cast them explicitly if you know the schema of your json.

Comment: @Manakin, thanks for your suggestion but my source data has floats, too, so I can't just convert every float to Int64. I've updated my description accordingly.

Comment: do you have an ever changing list of columns? if so you'll need to add some additional checks into your code. Personally, I would first check for float columns, of those float columns check to see if any columns have missing values. then of that sub selection of columns you could measure to see if there any floats by using `sum` or `mod` again this depends on your data and it's hard to give a generalised solution to an ever changing list of columns. If  you need help with coding the above let me know, but you seem advanced enough

Comment: No, it's a json array of records that have a fixed set of columns with some columns sometimes missing from individual records. In fact, originally I have a json string, so I just noticed that maybe something can be done during the `json.loads()` using the `parse_int` kwarg... I'll try that... I would almost consider this as a bug: having missing values should not mess up the type inference if the rest of the data is consistently of one specific type, imho.